# How to convert sqldatetime.minvalue to datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I can't seem to convert a sqldatatime.minvalue to a datetime object.

I tried:

```
Datetime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(SqlDateTime.MinValue);
```

That obviously didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for this. Your code helped me with reading a SQL return `DateTime dateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(8));`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Any reason not to just use the [explicit conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exzwfa5y.aspx)?

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime) SqlDateTime.MinValue;
```

That works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime) SqlDateTime.MinValue;
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: why would that work and not Convert.ToDateTime()  strange no?

Comment: @codecompleting, `Convert.ToDateTime` would need a proper overload to support the `SqlDateTime` value. The designers of `Convert` must not have considered it [important enough], whereas the designers of `SqlDateTime` certainly did.

Answer (score 180):

No need to convert.  `SqlDateTime` has a [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9x5ea6s.aspx) property that returns a `DateTime`.

```
DateTime dt = SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
```

Comment: A rare question where there is a better answer to Jon Skeets :-)

Comment: I did not see that coming.

Answer (score 18):

The answers you have received have shown you two different ways to convert the value. One is to use an explicit conversion defined for `SqlDateTime` to `DateTime`, the other is to access the `.Value` property on the `SqlDateTime` instance, which returns a `DateTime`.

```
var date = theSqlDate.Value; // via property
var date = (DateTime)theSqlDate; // via explicit conversion
```

There are tradeoffs that are worth considering. `SqlDateTime` supports the concept of null values in the database (DBNull, referenced by another now-deleted answer) through the value `SqlDateTime.Null`. If you access the `Value` property on a "null" instance, you will run into a `SqlNullValueException`. On the other hand, an explicit conversion to DateTime results in `{January 1, 1900 12:00:00 AM}`. Neither of these results may be desired in your code. Overwriting a valid null entry at the database with a non-null default value might be just as bad as getting an exception at runtime.

If you have a nullable column in the database, and if you are working with `SqlDateTime`, you may need to explicitly test for and treat `SqlDateTime.Null` differently, and then it might not matter which approach you take for converting other values.

```
DateTime? date;
if (theSqlDate.Equals(SqlDateTime.Null))
    date = null
else 
    date = theSqlDate.Value; // or (DateTime)theSqlDate;
```

Comment: It's a rare answer that's better than an answer that's better than Jon Skeet's.